# Bunch of cuComplex.h and cmath errors

Tags: gpgpu, matrix-multiplication, arrayfire

I am trying to compile my code in VSC++ using arrayfire for porting the matrix multiplication to gpu. I am getting the following bunch of errors for all the source files.
What's happening! I am pretty sure it's a silly mistake but please be kind enough to point that out for me.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <timing.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <arrayfire.h>

// *************************************************
#include "DMC.hxx"
```

using namespace af;

```
//MMUL(K1,  tmp1,tmp2); //my cpu version matrix multiplication
array K1 = matmul (tmp1,tmp2); //trying to do with arrayfire
//% K1 = (R1 - dy^2/48*iR2)\(eye(4*K) + i*(3-2*sqrt(3))/12*dy*iR2); (MATLAB version)

        #pragma omp parallel for private(ii,jj)
        for (ii=1;ii<=4*K;ii++)
        {
            for (jj=1;jj<=4*K;jj++)
            {
                tmp2.ld(ii,jj,  cmplx(0,(3.f+2.f*sqrt(3.f))/12.f*dy)* K1(ii,jj));
            } //end
            tmp2.ld(ii,ii,   tmp2(ii,ii)+(1.f)); // %eye
        } //end
```

********************  OUTPUT  ***********************

```
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\cuComplex.h(124): error C3861: 'fabsf': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\cuComplex.h(124): error C3861: 'fabsf': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\cuComplex.h(150): error C3861: 'fabsf': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\cuComplex.h(151): error C3861: 'fabsf': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\cuComplex.h(161): error C3861: 'sqrtf': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\cuComplex.h(234): error C3861: 'fabs': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\cuComplex.h(234): error C3861: 'fabs': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\cuComplex.h(258): error C3861: 'fabs': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\cuComplex.h(259): error C3861: 'fabs': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include\cuComplex.h(269): error C3861: 'sqrt': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(19): error C2039: 'acosf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(19): error C2873: 'acosf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(19): error C2039: 'asinf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(19): error C2873: 'asinf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(20): error C2039: 'atanf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(20): error C2873: 'atanf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(20): error C2039: 'atan2f' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(20): error C2873: 'atan2f' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(20): error C2039: 'ceilf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(20): error C2873: 'ceilf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(21): error C2039: 'cosf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(21): error C2873: 'cosf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(21): error C2039: 'coshf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(21): error C2873: 'coshf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(21): error C2039: 'expf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(21): error C2873: 'expf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(22): error C2039: 'fabsf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(22): error C2873: 'fabsf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(22): error C2039: 'floorf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(22): error C2873: 'floorf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(22): error C2039: 'fmodf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(22): error C2873: 'fmodf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2039: 'frexpf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2873: 'frexpf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2039: 'ldexpf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2873: 'ldexpf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2039: 'logf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(23): error C2873: 'logf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(24): error C2039: 'log10f' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(24): error C2873: 'log10f' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(24): error C2039: 'modff' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(24): error C2873: 'modff' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(24): error C2039: 'powf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(24): error C2873: 'powf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(25): error C2039: 'sinf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(25): error C2873: 'sinf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(25): error C2039: 'sinhf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(25): error C2873: 'sinhf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(25): error C2039: 'sqrtf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(25): error C2873: 'sqrtf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(26): error C2039: 'tanf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(26): error C2873: 'tanf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(26): error C2039: 'tanhf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(26): error C2873: 'tanhf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(28): error C2039: 'acosl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(28): error C2873: 'acosl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(28): error C2039: 'asinl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(28): error C2873: 'asinl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(29): error C2039: 'atanl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(29): error C2873: 'atanl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(29): error C2039: 'atan2l' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(29): error C2873: 'atan2l' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(29): error C2039: 'ceill' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(29): error C2873: 'ceill' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(30): error C2039: 'cosl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(30): error C2873: 'cosl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(30): error C2039: 'coshl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(30): error C2873: 'coshl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(30): error C2039: 'expl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(30): error C2873: 'expl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(31): error C2039: 'fabsl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(31): error C2873: 'fabsl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(31): error C2039: 'floorl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(31): error C2873: 'floorl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(31): error C2039: 'fmodl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(31): error C2873: 'fmodl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(32): error C2039: 'frexpl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(32): error C2873: 'frexpl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(32): error C2039: 'ldexpl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(32): error C2873: 'ldexpl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(32): error C2039: 'logl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(32): error C2873: 'logl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2039: 'log10l' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2873: 'log10l' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2039: 'modfl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2873: 'modfl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2039: 'powl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(33): error C2873: 'powl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2039: 'sinl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2873: 'sinl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2039: 'sinhl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2873: 'sinhl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2039: 'sqrtl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(34): error C2873: 'sqrtl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(35): error C2039: 'tanl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(35): error C2873: 'tanl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(35): error C2039: 'tanhl' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(35): error C2873: 'tanhl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(39): error C2039: 'acos' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(39): error C2873: 'acos' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(39): error C2039: 'asin' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(39): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

Comment: Please post some of the C/C++ code that you are attempting to compile. It looks like an include order problem (try copying the includes from one of the SDK demos)

Comment: @axon i dont think tats working!

Comment: Your code doesn't show where CUDA is being included. It also lacks basic structure like a 'main' function. It also depends on what is in DMC.hxx.

Comment: The code shown uses math functions like `sqrt()`, yet I don't see any inclusion of the header file `math.h`. What happens if you add that, or `cmath` in case this is compiled as C++ code. FWIW, I do not see where CUDA comes into play here at all? Are you compiling this code with nvcc, or cl ?

Comment: in DMC.hxx am using 
`float SQR(float f)
{return f*f;};`
I have tried including math.h, cmath. Not working, same errors!

Comment: @neonano I mentioned yesterday in our forums to put math.h *above* cuda. which means it needs to be above arrayfire.h as well. Never put arrayfire.h at the top!

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili Sorry i didn't understand well,i've edited the include file's order now. Is it OK. but still same errors!